# TSQL Drop FK in another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, sql-server-2014

MSSQL 2014

Is it possible to drop a FK in database2 whilst working in database1?

This isn't working for me

```
use database1
go

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database2.sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'fk_in_tbl_in_other_db') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'database2.dbo.tableName'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE database2.dbo.tableName DROP CONSTRAINT fk_in_tbl_in_other_db;
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to find a solution, Just a small modification to the WHERE clause

replace

```
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'fk_in_tbl_in_other_db')
```

with

```
WHERE name = N'fk_in_tbl_in_other_db'


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database2.sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = N'fk_in_tbl_in_other_db' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'database2.dbo.tableName'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE database2.dbo.tableName DROP CONSTRAINT fk_in_tbl_in_other_db;
END
```